# Is there a Twitter Streams API for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, twitter-streaming-api, tweetstream

Does anyone know of a Ruby gem or plugin that provides a simple interface to the [Twitter Steams API](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try TweetStream: https://github.com/intridea/tweetstream

Answer (score 0):

[Twitter](https://github.com/sferik/twitter)  Gem has added streaming functionality.
you can check that out